# Low Level Events in Solidity and log3 - uint to byte32

Tags: solidity

I have a question regarding low level events in solidity I can't really wrap my head around.

So in theory an event that looks like this:

```
event MyEvent(address indexed oneAddress, bool isTrueOrNot, uint256 myUnsingedNumber);
```

inside a function I would use it like that for example:

```
MyEvent(msg.sender, true, 5);
```

But now going to low-level events with log2 (log_i = i+1 parameters = 3). How would that be used there? I've tried around a bit but couldn't come up with the right solution...

```
log2(??, sha3("MyEvent(address,bool,uint256)"), msg.sender, ??)
```

In the samples in the Docs its quite straight forward, but I have real trouble putting that into this example here.

Here's the link to the docs: http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#events

Especially together with indexed, and uint256 to byte32 conversion, as all the parameters must be in byte32. Hope I haven't overlooked something...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the usage is log1( value, 'log_topic'); and then log2(value, 'log-topic1', 'log-topic2')

So if msg.sender is the value analyzed put it first in both cases.